# google chart data formatting error(javascript)

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, google-visualization

I'm calling a scatter plot with `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(loadGraphData);`
where loadGraphData is being generated from a backing bean in the form of an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` and looks like this:

```
"[['Date','Variable'], [0, 9.66], [1, 9.24], [2, 8.73], [3, 8.50]...]"
```

The data isn't loading the graph using the var, but if I paste the output in its place (without the quotes)the code works and correctly displays the data. is there a convenient way to remove the quotes, or am I taking the wrong approach?

BTW, I've replaced the dates with 0,1... as that was causing a different error I'm yet to fix.

the data comes from a JSF backing bean, extract below:

```
public ArrayList graphData(int variable, int nodeNumber)
    {
    Collection dataValues =  dataValuesFacade.findVariable(currentNodes.getCurrentNodes().get(nodeNumber), variable);
    ArrayList <DataValues> dataValuesArray = new ArrayList();
    dataValuesArray.addAll(dataValues);
    dataValues =  dataValuesFacade.findVariable(currentNodes.getCurrentNodes().get(nodeNumber), 0);
    ArrayList<DataValues> timeValuesArray = new ArrayList();
    timeValuesArray.addAll(dataValues);
    ArrayList <DataPairs> dataPairs = new ArrayList();
    dataPairs.add(new DataPairs());
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> returnData = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> newAL = new ArrayList();
    newAL.add("Date");
    newAL.add("Variable");
    returnData.add(newAL);
    //Gson gson = new Gson();

    for (int i=0;i<dataValuesArray.size();i++)
    {

        String varTimestamp = dataValuesArray.get(i).getdTimeStamp().toString();
        String dateTimestamp = timeValuesArray.get(i).getdTimeStamp().toString();
        String tempVariable = dataValuesArray.get(i).getdVariable().toString();
        String tempDate = timeValuesArray.get(i).getdVariable().toString();


        if ((varTimestamp.equals(dateTimestamp))&
                (dataPairs.get(i).getXdateStamp()==null)&
                (dataPairs.get(i).getYvariable()==null)&
                (dataPairs.get(i).getTimeStamp()==null))
        {
            dataPairs.get(i).setTimeStamp(dateTimestamp);
            dataPairs.get(i).setYvariable(tempVariable);
            dataPairs.get(i).setXdateStamp(tempDate);
            ArrayList<String> tempAL = new ArrayList();
            tempAL.add(i+"");
            tempAL.add(tempVariable);
            returnData.add(tempAL);
            dataPairs.add(new DataPairs());
        }
    }
    //String rt = gson.toJson(returnData);
    return returnData;
}
```

It's messy, but I've been trying all sorts of solutions, which need cleaning up.

Thanks

the exact output is as follows:

```
var loadGraphData = "[[Date, Variable], [0, 9.66], [1, 9.24], [2, 8.73], [3, 8.50], [4, 8.09], [5, 8.05], [6, 7.96], [7, 7.90], [8, 7.85], [9, 7.79], [10, 7.78], [11, 7.78], [12, 7.76], [13, 7.73], [14, 7.73], [15, 7.70], [16, 7.71], [17, 7.71], [18, 7.71], [19, 7.71], [20, 7.70], [21, 7.69], [22, 7.69], [23, 7.65], [24, 7.65], [25, 7.62], [26, 7.60], [27, 7.54], [28, 7.50], [29, 7.50], [30, 7.42], [31, 7.42], [32, 7.44], [33, 7.45], [34, 7.42], [35, 7.39], [36, 7.39], [37, 7.33], [38, 7.34], [39, 7.26], [40, 7.25], [41, 7.23], [42, 7.22], [43, 7.20], [44, 7.15], [45, 7.11], [46, 7.09], [47, 7.04], [48, 7.05], [49, 7.05], [50, 6.99], [51, 6.94], [52, 6.94], [53, 6.94], [54, 6.90], [55, 6.90], [56, 6.90], [57, 6.90], [58, 6.89], [59, 6.86], [60, 6.86], [61, 6.82], [62, 6.85], [63, 6.85], [64, 6.85], [65, 6.86], [66, 6.85], [67, 6.83], [68, 6.83], [69, 6.83], [70, 6.83], [71, 6.82], [72, 6.79], [73, 6.75], [74, 6.73], [75, 6.73], [76, 6.74], [77, 6.70], [78, 6.59], [79, 6.59], [80, 6.56], [81, 6.55], [82, 6.56], [83, 6.54], [84, 6.50], [85, 6.45], [86, 6.43], [87, 6.42], [88, 6.39], [89, 6.38], [90, 6.36], [91, 6.34], [92, 6.31], [93, 6.26], [94, 6.25], [95, 6.29], [96, 6.30], [97, 6.31], [98, 6.32], [99, 6.33], [100, 6.33], [101, 6.35], [102, 6.33], [103, 6.35], [104, 6.37], [105, 6.38], [106, 6.36], [107, 6.37], [108, 6.32], [109, 6.32], [110, 6.30], [111, 6.30], [112, 6.27], [113, 6.26], [114, 6.30], [115, 6.33], [116, 6.36], [117, 6.37], [118, 6.37], [119, 6.37], [120, 6.37], [121, 6.40], [122, 6.39], [123, 6.39], [124, 6.39], [125, 6.36], [126, 6.35], [127, 6.33], [128, 6.36], [129, 6.37], [130, 6.37], [131, 6.35], [132, 6.36], [133, 6.35], [134, 6.32], [135, 6.31], [136, 6.27], [137, 6.25], [138, 6.25], [139, 6.23], [140, 6.21], [141, 6.20], [142, 6.20], [143, 6.18], [144, 6.18], [145, 6.17], [146, 6.18], [147, 6.20], [148, 6.18], [149, 6.19], [150, 6.20], [151, 6.21], [152, 6.22], [153, 6.26], [154, 6.27], [155, 6.29], [156, 6.30], [157, 6.30], [158, 6.33], [159, 6.36], [160, 6.39], [161, 6.35], [162, 6.36], [163, 6.36], [164, 6.37], [165, 6.39], [166, 6.40], [167, 6.39], [168, 6.42], [169, 6.39], [170, 6.38], [171, 6.40], [172, 6.41], [173, 6.42], [174, 6.41], [175, 6.44], [176, 6.46], [177, 6.46], [178, 6.47], [179, 6.51], [180, 6.52], [181, 6.54], [182, 6.56], [183, 6.58], [184, 6.59], [185, 6.63], [186, 6.68], [187, 6.70], [188, 6.73], [189, 6.72], [190, 6.73], [191, 6.73], [192, 6.77], [193, 6.79], [194, 6.80], [195, 6.81], [196, 6.83], [197, 6.85], [198, 6.88], [199, 6.88], [200, 6.91], [201, 6.94], [202, 6.96], [203, 6.96], [204, 6.99], [205, 7.02], [206, 7.05], [207, 7.06], [208, 7.08], [209, 7.06], [210, 7.08], [211, 7.07], [212, 7.12], [213, 7.02], [214, 6.97], [215, 6.98], [216, 6.97], [217, 6.94], [218, 6.98], [219, 6.94], [220, 6.92], [221, 6.86], [222, 6.90], [223, 6.91], [224, 6.91], [225, 6.87], [226, 6.91], [227, 6.85], [228, 6.90], [229, 6.92], [230, 6.94], [231, 6.96], [232, 6.87], [233, 6.91], [234, 6.86], [235, 6.84], [236, 6.80], [237, 6.87], [238, 6.82], [239, 6.78], [240, 6.84], [241, 6.87], [242, 6.87], [243, 6.80], [244, 6.78], [245, 6.81], [246, 6.77], [247, 6.71], [248, 6.75], [249, 6.75], [250, 6.78], [251, 6.68], [252, 6.70], [253, 6.73], [254, 6.72], [255, 6.75], [256, 6.83], [257, 6.78], [258, 6.75], [259, 6.81], [260, 6.84], [261, 6.83], [262, 6.75], [263, 6.78], [264, 6.81], [265, 6.78], [266, 6.74], [267, 6.79], [268, 6.81], [269, 6.78], [270, 6.80], [271, 6.80], [272, 6.82], [273, 6.75], [274, 6.77], [275, 6.83], [276, 6.87], [277, 6.85], [278, 6.81], [279, 6.81], [280, 6.82], [281, 6.85], [282, 6.78], [283, 6.81], [284, 6.83], [285, 6.83], [286, 6.75], [287, 6.78], [288, 6.78], [289, 6.81], [290, 6.83], [291, 6.81], [292, 6.77], [293, 6.72], [294, 6.74], [295, 6.74], [296, 6.73], [297, 6.73], [298, 6.75], [299, 6.79], [300, 6.81], [301, 6.83], [302, 6.84], [303, 6.82], [304, 6.86], [305, 6.85], [306, 6.83], [307, 6.71], [308, 6.67], [309, 6.63], [310, 6.64], [311, 6.66], [312, 6.63], [313, 6.61], [314, 6.52], [315, 6.47], [316, 6.44], [317, 6.42], [318, 6.36], [319, 6.29], [320, 6.18], [321, 6.15], [322, 6.11], [323, 6.07], [324, 6.06], [325, 5.93], [326, 5.91], [327, 5.93], [328, 5.92], [329, 5.90], [330, 5.84], [331, 5.82], [332, 5.81], [333, 5.79], [334, 5.74], [335, 5.73], [336, 5.75], [337, 5.74], [338, 5.71], [339, 5.71], [340, 5.73], [341, 5.77], [342, 5.81], [343, 5.84], [344, 5.84], [345, 5.84], [346, 5.83], [347, 5.86], [348, 5.86], [349, 5.82], [350, 5.82], [351, 5.86], [352, 5.90], [353, 5.90], [354, 5.92], [355, 5.92], [356, 5.93], [357, 5.91], [358, 5.91], [359, 5.96], [360, 5.95], [361, 5.98], [362, 5.99], [363, 5.97], [364, 5.98], [365, 6.01], [366, 6.10], [367, 6.13], [368, 6.12], [369, 6.12], [370, 6.15], [371, 6.20], [372, 6.23], [373, 6.23], [374, 6.26], [375, 6.28], [376, 6.30], [377, 6.34], [378, 6.33], [379, 6.32], [380, 6.35], [381, 6.35], [382, 6.37], [383, 6.37], [384, 6.37], [385, 6.36], [386, 6.37], [387, 6.39], [388, 6.38], [389, 6.32], [390, 6.32], [391, 6.33], [392, 6.34], [393, 6.35], [394, 6.36], [395, 6.31], [396, 6.30], [397, 6.35], [398, 6.35], [399, 6.37], [400, 6.39], [401, 6.41], [402, 6.42], [403, 6.36], [404, 6.37], [405, 6.42], [406, 6.44], [407, 6.45], [408, 6.44], [409, 6.46], [410, 6.47], [411, 6.47], [412, 6.43], [413, 6.41], [414, 6.43], [415, 6.44], [416, 6.43], [417, 6.42], [418, 6.44], [419, 6.42], [420, 6.44], [421, 6.41], [422, 6.41], [423, 6.39], [424, 6.40], [425, 6.40], [426, 6.40], [427, 6.36], [428, 6.35], [429, 6.35], [430, 6.35], [431, 6.35], [432, 6.34], [433, 6.34], [434, 6.33], [435, 6.30], [436, 6.30], [437, 6.27], [438, 6.27], [439, 6.27], [440, 6.37], [441, 6.38], [442, 6.37], [443, 6.33], [444, 6.30], [445, 6.30], [446, 6.30], [447, 6.30], [448, 6.32], [449, 6.33], [450, 6.33], [451, 6.30], [452, 6.30], [453, 6.30], [454, 6.27], [455, 6.27], [456, 6.27], [457, 6.27], [458, 6.27], [459, 6.27], [460, 6.27], [461, 6.27], [462, 6.22], [463, 6.20], [464, 6.19], [465, 6.18], [466, 6.21], [467, 6.24], [468, 6.24], [469, 6.25], [470, 6.25], [471, 6.27], [472, 6.27], [473, 6.27], [474, 6.28], [475, 6.30], [476, 6.30], [477, 6.30], [478, 6.30], [479, 6.30], [480, 6.30], [481, 6.31], [482, 6.33], [483, 6.34], [484, 6.36], [485, 6.34], [486, 6.34], [487, 6.31], [488, 6.30], [489, 6.29], [490, 6.26], [491, 6.24], [492, 6.20], [493, 6.15], [494, 6.10], [495, 6.10], [496, 6.09], [497, 6.10], [498, 6.09], [499, 6.07], [500, 6.05], [501, 6.03], [502, 6.00], [503, 5.97], [504, 5.96], [505, 5.95], [506, 5.93], [507, 5.93], [508, 5.92], [509, 5.91], [510, 5.91], [511, 5.88], [512, 5.86], [513, 5.85], [514, 5.86], [515, 5.85], [516, 5.84], [517, 5.84], [518, 5.84], [519, 5.84], [520, 5.81], [521, 5.81], [522, 5.82], [523, 5.79], [524, 5.79], [525, 5.78], [526, 5.79], [527, 5.80], [528, 5.80], [529, 5.78], [530, 5.76], [531, 5.76], [532, 5.76], [533, 5.75], [534, 5.75], [535, 5.71], [536, 5.68], [537, 5.66], [538, 5.64], [539, 5.64], [540, 5.59], [541, 5.58], [542, 5.59], [543, 5.57], [544, 5.52], [545, 5.52], [546, 5.50], [547, 5.49], [548, 5.49], [549, 5.47], [550, 5.46], [551, 5.48], [552, 5.47], [553, 5.47], [554, 5.48], [555, 5.50], [556, 5.52], [557, 5.54], [558, 5.56], [559, 5.55], [560, 5.52], [561, 5.52], [562, 5.51], [563, 5.51], [564, 5.50], [565, 5.49], [566, 5.47], [567, 5.46], [568, 5.45], [569, 5.44], [570, 5.47], [571, 5.46], [572, 5.47], [573, 5.49], [574, 5.49], [575, 5.48], [576, 5.49], [577, 5.49], [578, 5.49], [579, 5.48], [580, 5.51], [581, 5.49], [582, 5.49], [583, 5.49], [584, 5.47], [585, 5.45], [586, 5.45], [587, 5.42], [588, 5.42], [589, 5.39], [590, 5.41], [591, 5.42], [592, 5.41], [593, 5.42], [594, 5.44], [595, 5.42], [596, 5.43], [597, 5.43], [598, 5.43], [599, 5.43], [600, 5.44], [601, 5.44], [602, 5.47], [603, 5.47], [604, 5.48], [605, 5.48], [606, 5.51], [607, 5.52], [608, 5.53], [609, 5.52], [610, 5.53], [611, 5.52]]";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the `arrayToDataTable()` member function expects an Array as an argument and you're passing a String.

One option that could work is first parsing the data that's being passed to you as JSON.  The only concern is the single-quotes wrapping `Date` and `Variable`.  Single-quotes are not valid JSON.  If you're in a position to change the response, you could just do this:

`google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(loadGraphData));`

Otherwise, if you need to deal with the single-quotes, you could replace them with double-quotes, then parse as JSON:

`google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(loadGraphData.replace(/'/g, '"'));`

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working unfortunately, I've changed the source to remove the single quotes and have made the suggested change, but the line is being skipped over in the compiler, so i can't check the output. do i need a custom library for JSON?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some code.  Can you edit your post to provide some context?  And no custom library needed for JSON -- it's a global object.  You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Comment: I think it'd actually be more help to see what `loadGraphData` looks like before you pass it to `arrayToDataTable()` since the issue you're having appears to be a JavaScript issue.  What is the value of `loadGraphData` before you pass it to `arrayToDataTable()`?  Try using `console.log(loadGraphData);`

Comment: There aren't any quotes around `Date` and `Variable`, so they can't be parsed as strings like they should be.  If there are single-quotes around `Date` and `Variable`, you can use the second solution I provided.  Otherwise, if you can put double-quotes around `Date` and `Variable`, then you can use the first solution.

Comment: as you can see from my code:      newAL.add("Date");
    newAL.add("Variable"); they do, but it's being removed. the code originally had single quotes but at your suggestion I removed them.

Comment: I meant you should remove your single-quotes in favor of double-quotes.  Double-quotes are valid JSON -- single-quotes are not.  If you weren't able to do that, then I gave you a solution where you could replace your single-quotes with double-quotes, so your array of arrays would become valid JSON.  Basically, put some quotes around your strings and choose a solution I've given you so you can parse your variable as valid JSON.